# Android Application

Tags: android

Hey i want to develop a player on Android, which can play streaming audio and video.how should i start about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should download the sdk http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: i have done with that part. i have also written a simple udp client and server program. When i compile them on regular machines they run perfectly. i then embedded the udp client code in Android simulator, it shows no response..:( The hello world program works perfectly in android simulator.

Comment: Audio and Video are not supported by the emulator